# Marshal slice of structs as slice of numbers

Tags: json, go, struct, marshalling, slice

I'm trying to figure out what is the best way to marshal to JSON string below structure:

```
type User struct {
    Id string    `json:"id"`
    Roles []Role `json:"roles"`
}

type Role struct {
    Id string    `json:"-"`
    Role int     
}
```

Get JSON output like: `{"id": "abc", "roles": [1, 2, 3]}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can implement any custom marshaling logic by implementing the [`json.Marshaler`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshaler) interface.

So simply implement the `MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error)` method on `Role`, in which you marshal it like a simple `int` number.

This is how it could look like:

```
func (r Role) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return json.Marshal(r.Role)
}
```

As you can see, `Role.MarshalJSON()` only marshals the `Role.Role` `int` field, and not the whole `struct`.

Testing it:

```
u := User{
    Id: "abc",
    Roles: []Role{
        Role{Id: "a", Role: 1},
        Role{Id: "b", Role: 2},
        Role{Id: "c", Role: 3},
    },
}
if err := json.NewEncoder(os.Stdout).Encode(u); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Output is as you expect it (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/sAhMOKA8q0D)):

```
{"id":"abc","roles":[1,2,3]}
```

Comment: Maybe add the unmarshaller to go with it (`strconv.Atoi(string(b))` and assign that to `r.Role`)

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I didn't want to include that as that wasn't the question, and marshaling `Role` this way results in data loss (e.g. `Role.Id` is lost). There is no obvious way to reconstruct `Role` from the integer only. A viable solution could be using a role registry.

Comment: Oh yeah, you'd  lose the Id value for sure (and more over, the role registry would have to be distributed, and discussing that is way out of scope). I just meant to point out that there is a `json.Unmarshaller` interface to match the `json.Marshaller`